# KVM vCPU: Creating VPS with more GHz

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vcpu

I was trying to find a suitable answer to my question about if it is possible to create 2 x 3 GHz guest on a host server that has 6 cores running at 2 GHz. As I understood I would have 12 GHz total and with vCPU I can have 2 x 3 GHz on a guest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't work like that. Among the reasons is that for a single thread, you can never get more than the 2 GHz clock speed one single core offers and virtualization is no trick around this fundamental restriction.